# Making a repeating alarm in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Ok, so I have 0 experience with this, yet I managed to put this together by reading from different forums:

```
:loop
"sndrec32 /play /close 
"C:\Users\...\sound.mp3"
timeout /t x
goto loop
```

It plays a sound every x seconds. Is there a way to make it play the sound without the media player popping-out on the screen, and when it's done playing the sound - to close itself (the player)? What about the command promt not popping-out on the screen? I basically want to have as few pop-ups on the screen as possible when launching the file.

Thanks!

EDIT: Solved, see my reply

Comment: You can't hide the console window unless you use another programming language.

Comment: I did it by creating a .vbs that "CreatesObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "Alarm.bat",0,True". Took me quite a lot to figure how to turn it off though

Answer (score 0):

With MediaPlayer [ActiveX object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564034(v=vs.85).aspx) . This could be problem for a people without installed MediaPlayer (e.g. Windows XP required genuine authentication in order to install it) and it can acts differently on different windows versions (e.g. on some windows version auto closing does not work as expected). [Here's my implementation](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/mediarunner.bat) (does not create temporary files).Example:

```
call mediaRunner.bat "C:\Windows\Media\Ring05.wav"
```

On every windows machine there are installed [SP ActiveX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722561(v=vs.85).aspx) objects which are capable to run `.wav` files (no mp3 and so on). Here's [one script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/spplayer.bat).Expample:

```
call spPlayer.bat "C:\Windows\Media\Ring05.wav"
```

and we have also HTA/InternetExplorer applications and their [**bgsound**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535198(v=vs.85).aspx) tag.[Which also allows you to control the volume of the played song](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/soundPlayer.bat):

```
call htaplayer.bat "C:\Windows\Media\Ring05.wav" -1000
```